# find out how many groups are in a list

Tags: algorithm, grouping, k-means

I have a list with each value in the interval 0..100.

Ex:

```
[0,1,2,20,21,29,30,31,31,32,89,90,91,92,92,92,92]
```

Is there an algorithm that will determine how many groups are in this list? For the above list it should say that there are 3 groups `(0..2), (20..32), (89..92)`.

As far as I know there is the k-means algorithm that will split the list in a certain number of groups, but in my case, I need to determine how many groups are in the first place, so k-means doesn;t really help for this.

I will need to do this in PHP if the language has any relevance.

Comment: It is not clear what makes a group. Eg. why is 20,21,29,30,31,31,32 considered as one group and not two groups like 20..21  and 29..32 ?

Comment: @EbbeM.Pedersen Yes, that would also be a valid answer. Ideally there would be a threshold to set so I would be able to tune the group size or limit the number of groups.

Comment: Is the list sorted? Otherwise, it would be helpful to do so to simplify further steps.  

If you have a fixed threshold which separates two groups, you can simply scan through the array, store the begin index `b` of the current group and every time you have a 'jump' in your values (`array[i] - array[i - 1] > threshold`) output the group from `b` to `i - 1` and set `b` to `i`

Comment: @Tobias: there is no fixed threshold. I would rather control a maximum number of possible groups

Comment: Then I have the following idea: Sort the array if necessary and compute the adjacent differences (`array[i] - array[i - 1]`), I'll call these *gaps*. If you want at most `k` groups, select the `k` largest gaps by sorting the gap array and selecting the `k`-largest value (if it is unique), or the first value larger than `k` as the threshold for the algorithm I described above.

Comment: @Tobias yes, that sounds doable. Can you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know that your groups are separable by a certain minimum distance `d`, you can count the groups as by counting all consecutive elements that are not in the same group:

```
Input: A, d
Output: num_groups

sort(A)
for i = 0 ... size(A) - 2
    if A[i + 1] - A[i] >= d
        num_groups++
```

If you have yet to determine the optimal minimum distance such that there are at most `k` groups, you can determine this value by computing the **adjacent differences** and selecting the `k`th largest element:

```
Input: A of size n, k
Output: d

sort(A)
adj_diff = array of n - 1 elements
for i = 0 ... n - 2
    adj_diff[i] = A[i + 1] - A[i]
sort(adj_diff)
d = adj_diff[n - 1 - k]
if d == adj_diff[n - 2 - k] // to make sure there are at most k groups,
    d++                     // otherwise we might have multiple groups
                            // with the same distance to their neighbors
```